# Organizing Django unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing

Right now I have my Django unit tests living at `mcif/tests.py`. I would prefer to have something more like `mcif/tests/foo_test.py`, `mcif/tests/bar_test.py`, etc., but if I organize my tests that way, Django flips out.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do or do I have to have all my tests in one file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to spread django unit tests over multiple files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248510/how-to-spread-django-unit-tests-over-multiple-files)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

From version 1.6 of Django, the test discovery mechanism changed. You no longer need to import everything from `tests/__init__.py`, but now you have to make sure that all your files containing tests match the pattern `test*.py`.

So, instead of having `app/tests/models.py` and `app/tests/views.py`, now you should have `app/tests/test_models.py` and `app/tests/test_views.py`.

You could also create a file named `app/tests/test.py` and include your other files from there. The thing is that the runner will look for files matching the pattern `test*.py` and execute them.

Comment: +1 for Django 1.6. Moreover the imports in `__init__.py` no longer work.

Comment: To add to this.

Create tests/ folder
add __init__.py (no imports)
create tests/tests.py (and place the imports in there)

That way you can leave of the test prefix of each test file. If thats preferred

Comment: also make sure tests.py is removed when tests packages is being used

Comment: I needed to create an (empty) `__init__.py` file in my `tests/` folder sothat Pylint doesn't show error about the views it can't resolve.

Comment: Reference: Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: How exactly do you "include your other files from there [test.py]?"  Do you mean import them?

Comment: It looks like creating files matching `test*.py` isn't enough: they should match `test_*.py`? Thank you for your answer! EDIT actually most everything works, but not `test-*.py`? :shrug:

Answer (score 17):

*Note: This describes behavior prior to Django 1.6. See [Artur Soler's answer for Django 1.6 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932450/2321643).*

Make a package:  `myapp/tests/`

Within the package, put as many different testing modules as you want.  In the `__init__.py` within `tests`, import the tests from those modules.  (Or some variation on this theme.)

edit: Wow, didn't notice you already mentioned a `tests` package.

The important thing is to get everything available from the package.  Django will get the tests from the package, so they have to be visible in `__init__.py`.

[edit: Added note about Django version 1.6]

Comment: No longer valid from Django 1.6, see my response below.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to [Artur Soler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117194/artur-soler)'s great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160688/organizing-django-unit-tests/20932450#20932450)...

You can also use the `--pattern` option to specify how your test files are named.

For example if your test files are named `foo_test.py`, `bar_test.py` and similar, you can use:

```
$ ./manage.py test --pattern="*_test.py"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your __init__.py put something like:

```
from foo_test import *
from bar_test import *
```

Comment: Does the package have to be registered with settings.py?

Comment: When you have a file called ```__init__.py``` then the folder will act as a module. As long as the folder's parent is in the ```sys.path``` for python then no extra "registration" in ```settings.py``` is required, just import and use.

Comment: I setup a test package in my app and in the `__inti__.py` I imported two modules - `tests.py` and `selenium_tests.py`. But how can I elect to run just the selenium tests? I tried `./manage.py test myapp.selenium_tests` or `./manage.py test myapp.tests.slenium_tests` but it doesn't recognize them.

Comment: You probably don't need to add ```myapp.```, and in general re-check your syntax for errors.

Comment: I think the `myapp` is necessary as I have `selenium_tests.py` in other apps. So any idea how I would select just the `selenium_tests` for a specific app?

Comment: In order to run it like `./manage.py test myapp.tests.selenium_tests` I think you would have to create a `selenium_tests` package rather than file...

Answer (score 0):

As @artur-soler explained,

Let's say you have an app named "AppName":

[image: AppName tests]

Your `__init__.py` **inside** the tests folder should consists of something like -

```
from AppName.tests import *
```