# How to split Django app tests across several files

Tags: django, unit-testing, file, split

I'm working on a Django 1.2 app and I'm a kind of beginner with the framework. I want to split my tests in several files for the app https://github.com/vkhemlan/BolsaTrabajo/tree/master/bolsa_trabajo, how I can do that? What configurations do I have to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organizing Django unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160688/organizing-django-unit-tests)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to spread django unit tests over multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248510/how-to-spread-django-unit-tests-over-multiple-files)

Comment: The link is dead. Relevant, minimal code should be included with the question so it's free of dependencies and won't rot like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a really good guide on testing django apps:
[A Guide to Testing in Django](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/)

And the [example app on github](https://github.com/toastdriven/guide-to-testing-in-django/tree/master/polls/tests) splits the tests for *forms*, *views* and *models* into separate files, so it is probably a good example for you.

Note how each test module gets imported in `__init__.py`:

```
from polls.tests.forms import *
from polls.tests.models import *
from polls.tests.views import *
```

Comment: As of Django 1.6 this no longer works. See this answer for an updated solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20932450/15676