# How to spread django unit tests over multiple files?

Tags: django, unit-testing

- I have a python-django application
- I'm using the [unit testing framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/)
- The tests are arranged in the file "tests.py" in the module directory
- I'm running the tests via `./manage.py test app`

Now..

- The `tests.py` file is getting rather large/complex/messy
- I'd like to break `tests.py` up into smaller collections of tests...

How?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The behavior has changed in Django 1.6, so there is no longer a need to create a package. Just name your files `test*.py`.

[From Django 1.7 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/overview/)

> When you run your tests, the default behavior of the test utility is
>   to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of unittest.TestCase)
>   in any file whose name begins with test, automatically build a test
>   suite out of those test cases, and run that suite.

From [Django 1.6 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/),

> Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test
>   discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named
>   “test*.py” under the current working directory.

Previous behavior, [from Django 1.5 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/):

> When you run your tests, the default behavior of the test utility is
>   to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of unittest.TestCase)
>   in models.py and tests.py, automatically build a test suite out of
>   those test cases, and run that suite.
>
> There is a second way to define the test suite for a module: if you
>   define a function called suite() in either models.py or tests.py, the
>   Django test runner will use that function to construct the test suite
>   for that module. This follows the suggested organization for unit
>   tests. See the Python documentation for more details on how to
>   construct a complex test suite.

Comment: In django 2.6 it doesn't really discover anything…

Comment: Currently using Django 1.10, I wanted to put all my `test*.py` files in a folder called `tests` to keep the folder clean - this is possible, but you must run `./manage.py test app.tests` and all relative imports need to go up a level (`from .models` becomes `from ..models`).

Comment: Putting all files into a single folder `tests`, I start testing just with `python manage.py test`. Important, name folder, classes and methods with prefix test.

Answer (score 139):

**Note that this approach is no longer valid from Django 1.6, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932450/117194).**

You can create `tests` folder with `___init___.py` inside (so that it becomes a package). Then you add your split test .py files there and import all of them in `___init___.py`.

I.e: Substitute the `test.py` file with a module that looks and acts like the file:

Create a `tests` Directory under the app in question

```
app
app\models.py
app\views.py
app\tests
app\tests\__init__.py
app\tests\bananas.py
app\tests\apples.py
```

Import the submodules into `app\tests\__init__.py`:

```
from bananas import *
from apples import *
```

Now you can use ./manage.py as if they were all in a single file:

```
./manage.py test app.some_test_in_bananas
```

Comment: Doh. You meant create a 'tests' module under the application I'm testing; not a new application called tests. I get it now. Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @John: I can't recognize my answer anymore! :-) But you are completely right that it was too vague, even if correct - your examples make it clear, contrary to my original wording.

Comment: @Tomasz.. Your words are still there - wholly intact. I just fleshed it out a little since you put me on the right track.

Comment: @John: I wasn't angry at all if that's what you mean :) It was just funny to see my own answer in a bit different shape

Comment: I have always been under the impression that this technique does not work with the regular django test runner as it uses __test__ and suite() to find the tests.

Comment: @jMyles, if by "regular django test runner" you mean `python manage.py test myapp` then in fact this answer does work just fine. (just tried it)

Comment: @ArturSoler is it really no longer valid? [the docs for 1.10 describe this approach under 'advanced'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#using-the-django-test-runner-to-test-reusable-applications)

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is to convert your sub-test folder created to a package by adding a blank.   ____init__.py.   file. After this, you actually don't need to do any import in your ____init__.py. As long as the files named in the sub-folder begin with test*, Django will look for it and run the test methods in it.

Comment: In `__init__.py` I had to do `from .bananas import *` (add a dot before the name of the file) but it worked otherwise.

Answer (score 29):

The answer as stated by Tomasz is correct. However, it can become tedious to ensure that the imports in `__init__.py` match your file structure.

To **automatically detect all tests in the folder** you can add this in `__init__.py`:

```
import unittest

def suite():   
    return unittest.TestLoader().discover("appname.tests", pattern="*.py")
```

This will allow you to run `./manage.py test appname` but won't handle running specific tests. To do that you can use this code (also in `__init__.py`):

```
import pkgutil
import unittest

for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    for name in dir(module):
        obj = getattr(module, name)
        if isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, unittest.case.TestCase):
            exec ('%s = obj' % obj.__name__)
```

Now you can run all your tests via `manage.py test app` or specific ones via `manage.py test app.TestApples`

Comment: Where do you place the second piece?

Comment: Both pieces go into `__init__.py`

Comment: Note that if any of your test package names coincide with top level module names which get imported during the test run, the pkgutil snippet will cause the import to fail because the tests get added as `sys.modules[packagename]`. A quick workaround is to `del` any that cause problems after the above. (Or you could rename your folders ;) )

Comment: This is great but I ran into an error where,  when running an app level test (`python manage.py test appName`) the second bit of code would throw an error stating that `__path__` was not available.  I avoided it by wrapping the second snippet in a `if '__path__' in locals():` check, which did the trick.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: +1 this also ensures that the __init__ file adheres to common coding standards, i.e. does not have * or unused imports

Comment: might also just do `issubclass(obj, unittest.TestCase)` for Python 2.6 compatibilty

Answer (score 26):

Just make your directory structure like this:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_one.py
        test_two.py
        ...
    ...
```

And `python manage.py test myapp` will work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#organizing-tests talks about splitting the files into modules, and the section right above it has an example.

Comment: The 'bit extra' I'm looking for, over rtfm, is the django settings environment, database, and fixtures for the tests.

Answer (score 4):

With Django 2.2 a simple and fairly good solution could be to create a `test` folder inside an app, and you can put your related `test_...py` files into, just add `__init__.py` to the `test` folder.

Answer (score 2):

No need to code anything in init.
Just create a subdirectory in your app. Only requirement is **not to call it tests***
For exemple

```
app/
app/__init_.py
app/serializers.py
app/testing/
app/testing/__init__.py
app/testing/tests_serializers.py
```

Comment: Why can you not call it something that starts with "tests"?

Comment: I'm using this answer with Django 1.11.4.  Reasons to use it:
(1) The file "app/testing/__init__.py" remains empty and
(2) The command remains the basic "python manage.py test app"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a more complicated setup, or don't want to use `from ... import *`-type statements, you can define a function called `suite` in your tests.py (or tests/__init__.py), which returns an instance of `unittest.TestSuite`.

Answer (score 1):

I have two files. One is `tests.py` and another is `test_api.py`. I can run these individually as below.

```
manage.py test companies.tests
manage.py test companies.test_api
```

Refer @osa's response about file naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

I think `./manage.py test` simply does running all the tests trick (in django >= 1.7).

If your *organizing tests* is about *grouping* and *cherrypicking* and you are fan of `nose` use [django nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose):

```
python manage.py test another.test:TestCase.test_method
```

If you know nose, then you know how to "wildcard" much nicer over all your files.

PS

It is just a better practice. Hope that helps. The answer was borrowed from here: [Running a specific test case in Django when your app has a tests directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875111/running-a-specific-test-case-in-django-when-your-app-has-a-tests-directory)

Answer (score 0):

In django you can use below comman or can check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/). Also using this command will pick up files with pattern you provide not just `test*.py` or `test_*`.py.

> **Documentation**
> You can specify a custom filename pattern match using the -p (or --pattern) option, if your test files are named differently from the test*.py pattern:

```
$ ./manage.py test --pattern="tests_*.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just create different test files with tests_name in your app

Say you have following test files:

```
tests_admins.py
tests_staff.py
tests_others.py
# will run both test files
(venv)..yourapp$./manage.py test --keepdb -v 2 appname
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in Windows, if you do not want to create a package (i.e folder with `__init__.py`) and just want to create a folder called "Tests" and this folder contains the test files then to run tests in cmd just enter

```
python manage.py test your_app_name/Tests
```

Since a path is expected