# Run multiple Django application tests with one command

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a Django project with multiple apps, `app_1`, `app_2`, and `app_3`. Currently, in order to run the test suite, I use the standard testing command: `python manage.py test`. This runs the tests for all of my apps. I am also able to run tests for a single app, specifically -- for example, `python manage.py test app_1/`. However, I'd like to be able to run all of the tests in some, but not all, of my apps. For example, I'd run `python manage.py test main_tests` and just have the tests in `app_1` and `app_2` run. Is there a way to do this?

I saw that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510680/how-do-i-group-unit-tests-in-django-at-a-higher-granularity-than-the-app) question specified how to run just a few tests within a single app, but not how to run just a few apps' tests within a project.

Answer (score 8):

You can supply multiple labels to the `test` command:

```
python manage.py test app_1 app_2
```

This will run all tests in `app_1` and `app_2`.