# Make Django test from a file NOT called tests.py?

Tags: django, unit-testing

Is there a way to make

```
python manage.py test
```

test from files other than mysite/tests.py?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible with some tomfoolery but I wouldn't recommend it due to the convention that Django has enforced, which, is very good and very reliable.

The reasoning behind that is that a Django project can consist of many apps. 
Each app with its own test file. This makes for good separation between the tests and apps and leaves your project "clutter free" if you will and you won't have to go through a massive test-file to add or remove tests.

Running these are then done on app basis:

**From the docs**

```
./manage.py test animals
```

or

```
./manage.py test polls
```

But it seems as you already know this :)

I would suggest reading this very with a capital V good SO post by Tomasz

[Spreading tests over multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248510/how-to-spread-django-unit-tests-over-multiple-files)

This doesn't answer your question but I thought it was "for good measure" and perhaps convince you that you might be barking up the wrong tree here :)