# Best practice for organizing selenium tests and unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-rc

So I am experimenting with the introduction of `selenium` unit tests in `django 1.4` in a couple of projects I am working on.

The standard way to run my unit tests are simply to do `./manage.py test` and I use `django-ignoretests` to exclude specific django apps that I do not want tested (as needed).

However, is there a way to configure my project so that I can decide to run **only** selenium tests when I want to and have `./manage.py test` run only standard unit tests.

What are some best practices for segregating and organizing selenium tests and standard unit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always group all your selenium tests under a single package `myapp/selenium_tests/` (as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5160779/1138710 for instance) and then run `manage.py test myapp.selenium_tests` and group the rest of tests under say `myapp/other_tests`.

Otherwise, I suppose you could write a test runner that checks for each test class whether it derives from `LiveServerTestCase` (see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#defining-a-test-runner)

Comment: As Selenium tests tend to be functional, I try to do the same, keeping them in a separate package, along with an option to skip them (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10743466/4281). I like the idea of the test runner, but in some cases the tests may not be a descendant of LiveServerTestCase (which is another issue).

Answer (score 5):

For the test classes in question, I added the following decorator:

```
from django.conf import settings
@unittest.skipIf(getattr(settings,'SKIP_SELENIUM_TESTS', False), "Skipping Selenium tests")
```

Then to skip those tests add to the settings file: `SKIP_SELENIUM_TESTS = True`

This could easily be wrapped into a subclass of LiveServerTestCase or a simple decorator. If I had that in more than one place, it would be already.