# Django test models get loaded depending on their location?

Tags: python, django, testing, python-import

I have a Django app which has this structure:

```
app/
    tests/
        __init__.py
        tests.py
    __init__.py
    test_model.py
```

In `tests.py` I import the test model like: `from app.test_model import *`. This works as expected: during testing, models are loaded, their corresponding database tables are created and so on.

But, if I move the `test_model.py` file in the `tests/` directory:

```
app/
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test_model.py
        tests.py
    __init__.py
```

And do the import accordingly: `from app.tests.test_model import *`, it suddenly fails. Models are not detected, hence their database tables are not created and tests start to fail (`DatabaseError: no such table: app_model`).

Why is this happening? How should I avoid this and still place the `test_model.py` file in `tests/`?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 1.4.10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organizing Django unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160688/organizing-django-unit-tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `test_models.py` is actually where you create all your models.  Django looks for the model app name as the parent folder, and nesting it as you have may cause it to get stuck finding the app name.  I don't fully understand the mechanics here, but I have experienced it before.  The simple solution is to manually specify the app using the [`Meta` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label):

```
class MyModel(Model):

    ...

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from test_model import *
```

try this, it may help

Answer (score -1):

You should use a local import within a package:

```
from .test_model import *
```

Comment: It's the same result, models defined in `test_model.py` are not loaded, neither their tables.

Comment: Then you might have overlooked creating the models dynamically as mentioned in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2672444/3107299)

Comment: @aquavitae's answer was cleaner and more 'Djangoish'. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: This is not correct, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160688/organizing-django-unit-tests/20932450#20932450](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160688/organizing-django-unit-tests/20932450#20932450)