# How to make `manage.py` search tests also in a `tests` subfolder and not only in the app toplevel directory?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests, manage.py, django-manage.py

This is my directory structure:

```
~
|--- scratchpad
     |--- manage.py
     |--- my_project
          |--- __init__.py
          |--- settings.py
          |--- urls.py
          |--- wsgi.py
          |--- my_app
               |--- __init__.py
               |--- admin.py
               |--- apps.py
               |--- models.py
               |--- tests.py
               |--- views.py
               |--- migrations
                    |--- __init__.py
```

The contents of `tests.py` are simple enough:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.

class TrivialTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_trivial(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

In this setting I can run my tests without problems:

```
m@mycomp:~/scratchpad$ python3 manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

BUT what if the `tests.py` file gets so large I'd like to split it into many smaller files AND move them all to a separate folder to keep the app directory clean?

```
~
|--- scratchpad
     |--- manage.py
     |--- my_project
          |--- __init__.py
          |--- settings.py
          |--- urls.py
          |--- wsgi.py
          |--- my_app
               |--- __init__.py
               |--- admin.py
               |--- apps.py
               |--- models.py
               |--- tests
                    |--- tests_trivial.py
               |--- views.py
               |--- migrations
                    |--- __init__.py
```

Now `manage.py` cannot find my tests!

```
m@mycomp:~/scratchpad$ python3 manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I am surprised because this behavior seems to contradict [certain highly upvoted answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160688/organizing-django-unit-tests/20932450#20932450), at least if I'm reading these answers right.

Now I can run my tests if I modify my command a little:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~/scratchpad$ python3 manage.py test my_project.my_app.tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

However typing all of this each time I want to run tests is a PITA.

Is there any way to make `manage.py` discover tests in the `tests` subfolder without having to type `my_project.my_app.tests` all the time?

Comment: Is there a file named `__init__.py` inside your `tests` folder?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo O_o now I'm startled. Well there was not. The surprising part (for me) was that adding `__init__.py` DID RESOLVE THE ISSUE! I thought python has already removed the need to add empty `__init__.py` files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3 Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Let me create an answer and will give you some more information about that.

Answer (score 1):

Every django-app test-folder needs the following structure to get the tests running properly::

```
|__django-app
    |__tests
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- test_models.py   
        |-- test_views.py
```

Important: Fill in an empty **__init__.py** File in every test-directory.

So, in your case it should be:

```
|--- scratchpad
     |--- manage.py
     |--- my_project
          |--- __init__.py
          |--- settings.py
          |--- urls.py
          |--- wsgi.py
          |--- my_app
               |--- __init__.py
               |--- admin.py
               |--- apps.py
               |--- models.py
               |--- tests
                    |--- __init__.py
                    |--- tests_trivial.py
               |--- views.py
               |--- migrations
                    |--- __init__.py
```

I highly recommend this tutorial William Vincent for beginning with testing with Django [Django Testing Tutorial](https://wsvincent.com/django-testing-tutorial/)