# Running Python Tests from Subpackages

Tags: python, django

I've got a package - we'll be creative and call it `package` - and in there are `api` and `dashboard` packages, each with a `tests` module and various files filled with tests.

I'm using Django test runner and rather than having `package.api.tests` and `package.dashboard.tests` in my run configs, I'd like to just have `package.tests` and have that run all the tests in the packages below it.

I added a `tests` package to `package` and in the **init** tried a few things like `from package.api.tests import *` or using an **all** declaration but that didn't work.

Is there a way to make this happen? It's not the most annoying thing in the world, but it's a package that gets brought in to each project we do, and it would just be a bit simpler to have instructions of "Run package.tests", especially if we end up adding more packages beyond api and dashboard.

Comment: Does this help ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932450/6505847

Comment: That did help unlock a few ways for me. I used the directory rather than the module names, so the test runner finds everything within that directory. No need to worry about packages at all. 

I also realized that `from package.api.tests import *` wouldn't work, as I had my tests there also split into separate files, so I could either import * from each test file, or use an __all__

I went with the directory approach as it was simpler. Appreciate the nudge. Is it fair to turn that into an answer, and I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the version of 1.6 in Django, you can:

> Have test files matching the pattern `test*.py`. You can therefore have test files in the form of `app/tests/test_models.py` and `app/tests/test_views.py`.

> You could also create a file named app/tests/test.py and include your
> other files from there. The thing is that the runner will look for
> files matching the pattern `test*.py` and execute them.

As you mentioned, `from package.api.tests import *` wouldn't have worked as the test functions could have been split into many different files. Therefore performing `import *` or using an all import approach is plausible in this case.