# How to have a fixture loaded for all Django tests in the test runner?

Tags: python, django, testing, fixtures

I have a large set of Django test cases, all of which subclass either `TestCase` or `TransactionTestCase`. I need to add a fixture to all test cases (to handle a new way of handling settings in the database).

I could of course add the fixture to the `fixtures` attribute of every test case. Or I could change the test cases to subclass from a custom test case subclass that sets this fixture -- and then change all existing test case fixture settings to extend rather than override the parent class fixture settings.

Either of the above would be tedious and error prone in this particular case.

So -- is there any way to get the test runner to always add a fixture to each test case as it's run?

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but, you could monkey-patch `TestCase` on the *module* level.

For example, something like this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

# The following line would be the only addition to your existing code:
TestCase.fixtures = ['my_fixture']  


class MyTests(TestCase):
    ...


class MyOtherTests(TestCase):
    ...
```

Now the fixtures would be loaded for all `TestCase`s in the module.

Even less pretty, you could do a similar thing on the project level, e.g. in `settings.py`, by monkey-patching as follows:

```py
import django.test

django.test.TestCase.fixtures = ['my_fixture']
```

As far as I know, Django's [fixture-loading documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading) does not provide any (alternative) solutions.

I do think there is something to say for loading test fixtures explicitly in each `TestCase`that actually needs them.