# Load Django Fixtures Once?

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979434/how-to-load-fixtures-only-once-in-django-unit-tests) was asked before, but I was wanting to see if there is a more updated solution. Would there be a way to load all my fixtures in `setUp` and and flush them when all tests are finished?

Right now, I'm loading in my fixtures like so...

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.management import call_command

class GlobalSetup(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # Load fixtures
        call_command('loaddata', 'test_cfst.json', verbosity=0)
        call_command('loaddata', 'test_lmt.json', verbosity=0)
        call_command('loaddata', 'test_qt.json', verbosity=0)

class BaseTest(GlobalSetup):
    fixtures = [
        'test_cfst.json',
        'test_lmt.json',
        'test_qt.json'
        ]

    def setUp(self):
        super(BaseTest, self).setUp()

    def test_base(self):
        # Some random tests
```

With the newer version of django is there a way, or better way, to do this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400697/) to your linked question says that the fixtures are loaded once for each test class since Django 1.8.

Comment: Ah, I dug through the 1.8 updates, but I skimmed right over the [TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#testcase-data-setup) part. My fault for not triple checking. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you are aware or not but you just load fixtures as below:

> ```
> from django.test import TestCase
> from myapp.models import Animal
>
> class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
>     fixtures = ['mammals.json', 'birds']
>
>     def setUp(self):
>         # Test definitions as before.
>         call_setup_methods()
>
>     def test_fluffy_animals(self):
>         # A test that uses the fixtures.
>         call_some_test_code()
> ```
>
> example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading)

So you don't need to write `GlobalSetup` with `call_command` as you did in your current example which is leading to load the fixtures twice. because the method is already called in setUpClass(refer this [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ab251fdad251cfb1e9fb61c42b5bfed9d0afe393/django/test/testcases.py#L1033))

Comment: I was not and this does help! I've just been trying to find tutorials on testing to better learn it, and was following [this one](http://blog.namis.me/2012/02/13/loading-fixtures-in-django-tests/) but it's a bit out of date. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: almost half decade older it is though.. that's why for starters you should follow documentation. and I am not aware of any such enrich documentation maintained as maintained by django. At some point it will also point you out about future deprecation too. and for upgrading django you should hence upgrade existing your project django version one by one and resolve the compatibility

Comment: Will do! I was looking at several of the docs, but always like to see if I can find some used examples to reference from. Thanks for all the advice!